# Python: newly made anki deck notes from genanki are invisible

Tags: python, openpyxl, anki

When creating the deck, upon import to Anki, Anki says the notes have been added yet I cannot find them anywhere in Anki's browser. Here's the code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import genanki
import random

beg = 1000000000
end = 9999999999
id_list = []
for i in range(0, 5000):
    randomNum = random.randint(beg,end)
    while randomNum in id_list:
        randomNum = random.randint(beg, end)
    id_list.append(randomNum)


model = genanki.Model(
  id_list[-1],
  'Simple Model',
  fields=[
    {'name': 'Meaning'},
    {'name': 'Arabic Spelling'},
    {'name': 'Phonetic Spelling'},
    {'name': 'Audio'},
  ],
  templates=[
      {
        'name': 'Only Card',
          'qfmt': 'How do you say:<div style="font-family: Arial; font-size:             
                  40px; padding: 20px;">{{Arabic Spelling}}</div>',
          'afmt': '{{FrontSide}}<hr id=answer><div style="font-family: Arial;     
                  font-size: 20px; padding: 20px;">{{Meaning}}</div><div 
                  style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; padding: 20px;"> 
                  <em>{{Phonetic Spelling}}</em></div><div style="font-family:         
                  Arial; font-size: 20px; padding: 20px;">{{Audio}}</div>',
      },
  ])
del id_list[-1]



my_deck = genanki.Deck(
  id_list[-1],
  'test')
del id_list[-1]

wb = load_workbook("all_words.xlsx")
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('ALL WORDS')
englishWordList = []

for col_cells in sheet.iter_cols(min_row=2, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    for cell in col_cells:
        englishWordList.append(cell.value)

i = 0
for word in englishWordList:
    note = genanki.Note(
        sort_field=id_list[i],
        model=model,
        fields=[word, "", "", ""]
    )
    my_deck.add_note(note)
    i = i + 1
i = 0
genanki.Package(my_deck).write_to_file("testOutput.apkg")
```

The output is a anki deck that has all the notes created yet I can't find them anywehre in the browser of Anki. Anki tells me to "clean database" since the database is in an "inconsistent state". Below are two pics: proof of the addition of notes and the error description:
[image]
[image]

Additionally I have tried to disable all add ons that may interfere. It has not worked or changed the results. Can anyone help with this? I have thought that maybe Anki needs a card created in order to reveal the note in the Anki Browser, yet genanki has no instructions on how to create a card. Genanki documentation: [genanki readme](https://github.com/kerrickstaley/genanki)

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER: When generating notes, make sure that the {{FrontSide}} has data - my script above doesn't have data in the "Arabic Spelling" field which goes on the front. If there's nothing on the front of the card, there will not be any card generated. Notes will be generated, but they are inaccessible.

I was also informed there could be issues with the assignment of the sort_field from my array id_list. For further explanation see this reddit post: [my reddit post.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Anki/comments/czi68k/genanki_issues_imported_notes_are_there_but/)